# TclXML/tcl: Installing on Windows

Tags: xml, windows, tcl

I am trying to install the TclXML/tcl package on a Windows machine.

According to the [Read Me](http://tclxml.sourceforge.net/tclxml/3.2/README.html#id18619), this should be a breeze as one just needs to "run the configure script and invoke the command: make install".

But unfortunately, the configure script seems to require bash or some other UNIX-like shell to be run, and I am on Windows (7, to be precise).

Goolge did not turn up any How-Tos and neither did a search on this site. I hope you can advice.

Comment: You should look to see if you can use tDOM instead. It's how most Tcl programmers approach XML and it's very good (provided you want to work with DOM trees at all).

Comment: Otherwise I think you can copy/paste the .tcl and .tm files in the C:/tcl/lib/teapot/package/tcl/lib directory (and subdirectories as required) and edit the pkgIndex.tcl... though I did it only once and I have found a workaround for installing the package I needed. There should already be some packages there which can help you know what kind of structure you need to put the files in.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems, tDOM does not support XPath, but I will try to work with it anyways as I was able to install it without hassle (by copying the binary distribution contents into the TCL lib directory) ;-)

Comment: You can also have a look at _cygwin_

Comment: @MotKohn I am looking forward installing TclXML on Windows as well. I am interested about your comment related to *Cygwin*. I have a 64-bit versions of Tcl and MSys (but I can install Cygwin or Babun if needed).

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. I don't have experience with using TclXML but have had tremendous success using cygwin with many posix/unix programs that's why I just commented "have a look ...". Also I'm not sure why msys won't suffice. OP sounded like s/he does not even have a Bash console but msys has it.